Is it possible with xy to "extend" an arrow in such a way that it enters the box containing an object?
I would like to draw an arrow in xy that visits all the entries of a $4 \times 4$ grid like the one below

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix @=0ex @W=4ex @H=4ex @*[F-]{
\save
*{}
\ar `[rrr]
        `[rrrd]
        `^d[d]
        `^r[dd]
        `[ddrrr]
        `[dddrrr]
        [ddd]
\restore
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} \\
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} \\
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} \\
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet}
}
\]

\end{document}

However, I would like that it enters the last square as well, instead of stopping at the border. Is it possible to do so?
I figured out how to let it start from inside the box, but I did not find a solution for ending in the box.

I'm not an expert of xymatrix, but this seems to work:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix @=0ex @W=4ex @H=4ex @*[F-]{
\save
*{}
\ar `[rrr]
        `[rrrd]
        `^d[d]
        `^r[dd]
        `[ddrrr]
        `[dddrrr]
        [ddd]+<2pt,0pt>
\restore
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} \\
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} \\
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} \\
{\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet} & {\bullet}
}
\]

\end{document}


